# Making a custom dialog undismissable in android

Tags: android, android-dialog, customdialog

I have a custom dialog which have 2 progress bars and a button on it.
I am showing this dialog in `onPreExecute ()`of an AsyncTask and dissmissng it `onPostExecute()`
the problem is that when ever i touch screen during the operation the dialog dissmiss. I want it to only dismiss when cancel button on dialog is pressed or downloading files is complete.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

[reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

To nr4bt's answer: set it when you declaring your custom dialog in activity or etc

```
inActiveFragment = new InactiveDialogFragment();
inActiveFragment.setCancelable(false);
```